# Search gmail with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, search, gmail

I am trying to use an array:

```
[email@stackoverflow.com, emailaddress@two.com, emailaddress@three.com]
```

To search gmail to see if I have sent any messages to the above addresses in the last 7 days.

My search query is currently:

```
 for(var EveryWeekPerson in ArrayListedAbove){
    EveryWeekPerson.toString();

    var Emails = GmailApp.search('is:sent from:me to:' + EveryWeekPerson + '-in:chats newer_than:' + VariableStatingSevenDays);}
```

But this doesn't appear to be working and logging the output gives me the number 0, 1, 2 (I assume the position of the item in the array).

Ultimately I want to count how many emails were sent and if the number is zero perform some action.

I can't work out from the documentation what format the array needs to be in to to loop through it.

Comment: try a space in front of `-in`, otherwise you're doing ` to:email@stackoverflow.com-in:chats`, and the `-in` stuff MAY be treated as part of the email.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately didn't make a difference.

Comment: Perhaps it is the time variable that is wrong. Should that be 7 or 7d or some other variant?

Comment: I have gone for 7d as a string as it appears to state in the documentation (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - using the `for(var EveryWeekPerson in ArrayListedAbove)` enumerates while iterating (hence the 0, 1, 2 etc).

Instead you want

```
var ArrayLength = ArrayListedAbove.length()

for (var i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++) {
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:sent from:me to:' + ArrayListedAbove[i] + ' -in:chats newer_than:' + VariableHolding7Days);
}
```

Essentially go through the array and take each object by its index